# Is ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer faster than Items.IndexOf?

Tags: .net, wpf

Is `ItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer` faster than `ItemsControl.Items.IndexOf` called for corresponding item?

Comment: It probably depends on the content of the list. Have you tried profiling it?  And are you aware that the two aren't equivalent and thus aren't always interchangeable?

Comment: @Dan Puzey Maybe I'm stupid for not seeing it but when they work differently? Aren't they supposed to be equivalent?

Comment: No.  `Items.IndexOf` will give you the index of an item in the source data for the `ItemsControl`.  `ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer` gives you the index of an item based on the control being used to display the item in the `ItemsControl`.